# Reset call on Jasmine spy does not return

Tags: javascript, jasmine, spy, jasmine2.0

I'm using a Jasmine (2.2.0) spy to see if a certain callback is called.

Test code:

```
it('tests', function(done) {
  var spy = jasmine.createSpy('mySpy');
  objectUnderTest.someFunction(spy).then(function() {
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
});
```

This works as expected. But now, I'm adding a second level:

```
it('tests deeper', function(done) {
  var spy = jasmine.createSpy('mySpy');
  objectUnderTest.someFunction(spy).then(function() {
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    spy.reset();
    return objectUnderTest.someFunction(spy);
  }).then(function() {
    expect(spy.toHaveBeenCalled());
    expect(spy.callCount).toBe(1);
    done();
  });
});
```

This test never returns, because apparently the `done` callback is never called. If I remove the line `spy.reset()`, the test does finish, but obviously fails on the last expectation. However, the `callCount` field seems to be `undefined`, rather than `2`.

Comment: Try adding rejection handlers for your promises.

Comment: added `.catch(done)` to the end of the chain, same problem occurs. So @Daniel, if it's throwing I can't detect it.

Comment: Adding a `try/catch` does reveal the exception: `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'spy.reset()')`. I'm not sure why this isn't correctly handled by Q / Jasmine. I'm also not sure why my spy is missing several properties it normally should have.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The syntax for Jasmine 2 is different than 1.3 with respect to spy functions.
See Jasmine docs [here](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html#section-Spies%20here).

Specifically you reset a spy with `spy.calls.reset();`

This is how the test should look like:

```
// Source
var objectUnderTest = {
    someFunction: function (cb) {
        var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (true) {
                cb();
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(new Error("something bad happened"));
            }
        });
        return promise;
    }
}

// Test
describe('foo', function () {
    it('tests', function (done) {
        var spy = jasmine.createSpy('mySpy');
        objectUnderTest.someFunction(spy).then(function () {
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        });
    });
    it('tests deeper', function (done) {
        var spy = jasmine.createSpy('mySpy');
        objectUnderTest.someFunction(spy).then(function () {
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            spy.calls.reset();
            return objectUnderTest.someFunction(spy);
        }).then(function () {
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(spy.calls.count()).toBe(1);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/k1okzfr7/)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to write it:

```
const spy = spyOn(foo, 'bar');
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
spy.calls.reset();
```

Comment: If you are using typescript, very likely bar method does not have calls key.

Comment: Good call. Fixed.